# How to store and access JSON in iOS with Parse Server API format?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, alamofire, swifty-json

My JSON format:

```
   {
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "1a8SJaCo2P",
            "Name": "Banyan Tree",
            "Amount": 300,
            "Area": "Nizampura",
            "Cuisins": [
                "Asian",
                "Italian",
                "Chaat",
                "Awadhi"
            ],
            "Facility": [
                "Music",
                "Smoking Area",
                "Take Away",
                "Home Delivery"
            ],
            "Restaurant_Images": {
                "__type": "File",
                "name": "a138194bc773ffa570a27a640d66f89f_5.jpg",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

I know how to parse basic json format but it has a {"results":[{user1},{user2},....]} data. So how to parse it?

This is the back4app(parse.com) api requested format

Comment: Can you show me your cloud code function

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are getting serialized data or rawData. But I'll assume you are getting rawData. So, you may try the following

```
let serializedJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers)
    if let expectedResults = serializedJson as? [String:Any] {
        if let users = expectedResults["results"] as? [Any] {
            for user in users {
                //you will get the values 
                // now if it is parseable to PFUser
                //Then you can have
                if let user = user as? PFUser {
                    //you will have individual user
                }
               //If not parseable to PFUSer then you can parse it manually
            }
        }
    }
```